# Background images in CSS media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, background-image

I'm not sure how to test this so perhaps someone here has got the answer:

I've got a set of media queries (480, 768, 1024 and 1200) and I thought about assigning different background sizes to each and every one of these with the goal being to minimize loading time for mobile devices that doesn't need a background image being 1600 pixels wide.

Is this a really the way to do this or will all of the backgrounds be loaded anyways since they're in the CSS?

Comment: If you strictly load them from the media queries, then your approach would be right. If you are loading a large one by default outside of them, then it would be different. I mean, that one would be loaded always.

Comment: Great, thanks! I also found this post where I suppose that example number 5 is applicable. http://cloudfour.com/examples/mediaqueries/image-test/

Comment: Oh well, and I was thinking on assigning the background directly inside the media queries. Would that be wrong?

Comment: No, absolutely not. That seems to work just the way I was hoping it would.

Comment: I think the images will all be downloaded and parsed anyway (but not applied / displayed)

Comment: @LDJ According to the tests in the link above they don't.